# Testing Journey not working as expected

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm using an automated filtered DE as my entry source for a Journey. I'm using the test function to test how the records will flow into my DE. Yesterday when testing, the records were flowing into the paths, but today, the new leads that enter my filtered DE are not testing. The wheel just keeps spinning.

Is there a technical reason why this would be happening? The records are filtering in fine into my entry, they just don't want to test when selecting records.

Other items of note: Contact re-entry is set to Enter Anytime.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve had issues with the test feature in Journey Builder ever since it was released. I would recommend shortening any Wait Activities and add test records to the data extension, click Activate, and test that way.

See similar post here: [Known issues w/ Journey Builder new Testing feature?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/238558/known-issues-w-journey-builder-new-testing-feature/256870#256870)